# How can I optimise out this nested for loop?

Tags: objective-c, macos, optimization, foundation

How can I optimise out this nested for loop?

The program should go through each word in the array created from the word text file, and if it's greater than 8 characters, add it to the `goodWords` array. But the caveat is that I only want the root word to be in the goodWords array, for example:

If greet is added to the array, I don't want greets or greetings or greeters, etc.

```
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/james/dev/WordParser/word.txt" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    NSArray *words = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r\n"];
    NSMutableArray *goodWords = [NSMutableArray array];
    BOOL shouldAddToGoodWords = YES;

    for (NSString *word in words)
    {
        NSLog(@"Word: %@", word);

        if ([word length] > 8)
        {
            NSLog(@"Word is greater than 8");

            for (NSString *existingWord in [goodWords reverseObjectEnumerator])
            {
                NSLog(@"Existing Word: %@", existingWord);
                if ([word rangeOfString:existingWord].location != NSNotFound)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Not adding...");
                    shouldAddToGoodWords = NO;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (shouldAddToGoodWords)
            {
                NSLog(@"Adding word: %@", word);
                [goodWords addObject:word];
            }
        }

        shouldAddToGoodWords = YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
//load the words from wherever
NSString * allWords = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/usr/share/dict/words"];
//create a mutable array of the words
NSMutableArray * words = [[allWords componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] mutableCopy];
//remove any words that are shorter than 8 characters
[words filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length >= 8"]];
//sort the words in ascending order
[words sortUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

//create a set of indexes (these will be the non-root words)
NSMutableIndexSet * badIndexes = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
//remember our current root word
NSString * currentRoot = nil;
NSUInteger count = [words count];
//loop through the words
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    NSString * word = [words objectAtIndex:i];
    if (currentRoot == nil) {
        //base case
        currentRoot = word;
    } else if ([word hasPrefix:currentRoot]) {
        //word is a non-root word.  remember this index to remove it later
        [badIndexes addIndex:i];
    } else {
        //no match. this word is our new root
        currentRoot = word;
    }
}
//remove the non-root words
[words removeObjectsAtIndexes:badIndexes];
NSLog(@"%@", words);
[words release];
```

This runs very very quickly on my machine (2.8GHz MBP).

Comment: @Jasarien you might want to do a bit more than just `hasPrefix:`, since `hasPrefix:` is case sensitive...

Comment: It worked nicely. The whole file is made of lower case words so it wasn't a problem.

Answer (score 2):

A [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) seems suitable for your purpose. It is like a hash, and is useful for detecting if a given string is a prefix of an already seen string.

Answer (score 1):

I used an `NSSet` to ensure that you only have 1 copy of a word added at a time. It will add a word if the `NSSet` does not already contain it. It then checks to see if the new word is a substring for any word that has already been added, if true then it won't add the new word. It's case-insensitive as well.

What I've written is a refactoring of your code. It's probably not that much faster but you really do want a tree data structure if you want to make it a lot faster when you want to search for words that have already been added to your tree.

Take a look at [RedBlack Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) or [B-Trees](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/btreedbclass.aspx).

**Words.txt**

```
objective
objectively
cappucin
cappucino
cappucine
programme
programmer
programmatic
programmatically
```

**Source Code**

```
- (void)addRootWords {

    NSString        *textFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"words" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString        *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    NSArray         *wordFile = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    NSMutableSet    *goodWords = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

    for (NSString *newWord in wordFile)
    {
        NSLog(@"Word: %@", newWord);
        if ([newWord length] > 8)
        {
            NSLog(@"Word '%@' contains 8 or more characters", newWord);
            BOOL shouldAddWord = NO;
            if ( [goodWords containsObject:newWord] == NO) {
                shouldAddWord = YES;
            }
            for (NSString *existingWord in goodWords)
            {
                NSRange textRange = [[newWord lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[existingWord lowercaseString]];
                if( textRange.location != NSNotFound ) {
                    // newWord contains the a substring of existingWord
                    shouldAddWord = NO;
                    break;
                }
                NSLog(@"(word:%@) does not contain (substring:%@)", newWord, existingWord);
                shouldAddWord = YES;
            }
            if (shouldAddWord) {
                NSLog(@"Adding word: %@", newWord);
                [goodWords addObject:newWord];
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"***Added words***");
    int count = 1;
    for (NSString *word in goodWords) {
        NSLog(@"%d: %@", count, word);
        count++;
    }

    [goodWords release];
}
```

*Output:*

```
***Added words***
1: cappucino
2: programme
3: objective
4: programmatic
5: cappucine
```

Comment: When you say "make it work", could you explain what was wrong with it in the first place? It works for me, it just takes about 4 minutes to process 170,000 words... And, don't worry, it isn't homework.

Comment: @Jasarien: Sure no worries, try this one.